# Subsets of elements of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Can anyone help me to generate all the subsets of a given set?

Example:If I have [2,3,4] and if I want K=2, that means I need pairs of two => [[2,3], [3,2], [2,4], [4,2], [3,4], [4,3]]

I wrote this code, but it generates only the number of subsets:

```
arrange::Int->Int->Int
arrange n 1=n
arrange n r=n*arrange (n-1) (r-1)
```

Another version, but this doesn't generate all solutions of the subsets:

```
  arrange 0 _ =[[]]
  arrange _ []=[]
  arrange n (x:xs)=(map(x:)) (arrange (n-1) xs)++
                   (arrange n xs)
```

Comment: No. But if you have any idea for my example, please help me with an implementation.

Comment: the appropriate name is subset and not  "Arrangements of a list". please update your question. I've added an answer for what you are looking for..

Comment: @DeJaVo, no, that is not the appropriate name either. "Subsets" suggests that order does not matter. According to Wikipedia, these are called "partial permutations", or when specific sizes are known, "k-permutations of n" (e.g., 2-permutations of 3).

Answer (score 3):

Well based on your example this is a possible solution:

```
import Data.List (permutations)

pick :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
pick 0 _ = [[]]
pick _ [] = []
pick n (x:xs) = map (x:) (pick (n-1) xs) ++ pick n xs

arrange :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
arrange n = concatMap permutations . pick n
```

#### example

```
λ> arrange 2 [2,3,4]
[[2,3],[3,2],[2,4],[4,2],[3,4],[4,3]]
```

as you can see the trick is just picking a number of elements and then getting all permutations of the results (using `concatMap` to concat them together)

of course this might be homework so you might want to implement `permutations` by yourself ;)

Comment: I wrote the code for permutations, but it still doesn't work.                                   'import Data.List (delete)'
    pick :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
    pick 0 _ = [[]] 
    pick _ [] = []
    pick n (x:xs) = map (x:) (pick (n-1) xs) ++ pick n xs


    permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]
    permutations [] = [[]]
    permutations xs = [ x:ys | x <- xs, ys <- permutations (delete x xs)]


    arrange :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
    arrange n = concatMap permutations . pick n

Comment: I get this error: ERROR file:{Hugs}\An III\Haskell\aranj2.hs:10 - Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : permutations
*** Type          : [a] -> [[a]]
*** Given context : ()
*** Constraints   : Eq a

Comment: And if I modify the declaration of permutations with this one
permutations :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]], I get this error: Cannot justify constraints in explicitly typed binding
*** Expression    : arrange
*** Type          : Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
*** Given context : ()
*** Constraints   : Eq a

Comment: well using `delete` you have to include the `Eq a` everywhere you are using it (including my `arrange`) but there is a way (obvious) of writing `permutations` without delete ;) - but yours is fine - just add the constraints

Comment: Thank you for your indications. It helps me a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help - if this answers your question you might want to accept it - if not I will happily try to help you further

Comment: Could you explain what the pick function actually does?

Comment: @JavascriptLoser it generates a list of ways to pick n elements from the input list (without reordering) - for example `pick 2 [1,2,3] = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]`